# How to connect UaExpert to UaServer accepting certificate + username/password?

Tags: ssl, opc-ua

I've created my own certificate and private keys (ownCert.der and ownKey.pem). I've added the certificate to a OPC UA Server as a Trusted Cert. The OPC UA Server is also configured to allow access with a username/password as well. So both are required, a certificate + username/password.

When I connect to the Server using python, it works. Here the code I use:

```
from opcua import Client
from opcua import ua
client = Client("opc.tcp://serverUrl:4810")
client.set_user('myUsername')
client.set_password('myPassword')
client.application_uri = 'urn:Foo:serverUrl:UaClient:UUID'
client.set_security_string('Basic256Sha256,SignAndEncrypt,/path/to/ownCert.der,/path/to/ownKey.pem')
client.connect()
print ("connected")
client.disconnect()
```

The snippet above works, once connected I can browse, read, etc..

On UaExpert, I then create a new Server connection and entered the same data:
[image: UaExpert Settings]

When I click on connect, I get the "BadSecurityChecksFailed" error:

[image: Connection log on UaExpert]

Looking at the log, it seems that UaExpert is trying to connect using certificate only, and NOT certificate + username/password.

How can I connect to the server using UaExpert?

Answer (score 0):

The certificate used when opening a secure channel (the Application Instance certificate) is not the same as one used to authenticate a session, and is not related at all.

Right now the likely problem is that your server does not trust UaExpert's Application Instance certificate. UaExpert also needs to trust the server's AI certificate, but it usually prompts you to do so during the connection setup.

Comment: and how to set UaExpert to do what I need?